# Angular unit testing, what's causing the $rootScope.$watch() to fire?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

This is my Controller.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    app.controller('NavController', navController);

    function navController($rootScope, $scope, $location, $window, NavFactory) {

        $scope.menuConfig = null;
        $scope.menuItems = [];
        $scope.isActive = isActive;
        $scope.toggleBurgerMenu = toggleBurgerMenu;
        $scope.toggleDeviceSettings = toggleDeviceSettings;

        $rootScope.$watch('dictionary', function(dictionary) {
            if (dictionary) {
                init();
            }
        });

        function init() {
            $scope.menuConfig = $rootScope.config.navigation;
            NavFactory.GetMenuItems().then(onGetMenuItems, $scope.onAPIError);
        }

        function onGetMenuItems(response) {
            $scope.moduleConfig = response.moduleConfig;
            $scope.menuItems = response.menuItems;
        }
    }
})();
```

This is my Test suite (karma, jasmine)
describe('NavController function', function() {

```
var $rootScope, $scope, $location, $window, $controller, createController, NavFactory, CacheFactory, toastr;

beforeEach(module('mockedDashboard'));

beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _$location_, _$window_, _NavFactory_, _toastr_) {
    $location = _$location_;
    $window = _$window_;
    toastr = _toastr_;

    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $rootScope.dictionary = jsDictionary;
    $rootScope.config = jsConfig;
    $rootScope.config.contentFolder = '_default';

    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $scope.burgerMenuActive = false;
    //mock the parent controller function
    $scope.navigate = function(path) {
        $location.path('/' + path);
    };
    // end mock

    createController = function() {
        return _$controller_('NavController', {
            '$scope': $scope
        });
    };
    $controller = createController();
}));

// We are using CacheFactory in this project, when running multiple tests on the controller
// we need to destroy the cache for each test as the controller is initialized for each test.
afterEach(inject(function(_CacheFactory_) {
    CacheFactory = _CacheFactory_;
    CacheFactory.destroy('defaultCache');
}));

describe('init()', function() {

    it('should call NavFactory.GetMenuItems and set moduleConfig and menuItems on $scope', inject(function(_$httpBackend_) {

        var $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

        expect($scope.moduleConfig).toBe(undefined);
        expect($scope.menuItems.length).toBe(0);

        var responseData = [{
            "path": "stats",
            "url": "./app/modules/dashboard/modules/score/score.index.html",
            "icon": "fa fa-fw fa-pie-chart",
            "dashboardEnabled": true,
            "burgerMenu": true,
            "barMenu": false,
            "barMenuOrder": -1,
            "bottomMenu": true,
            "bottomMenuOrder": 3,
            "order_sm": 1,
            "order_md": 2,
            "order_lg": 2
        }];

        $httpBackend.expectGET('../content/_default/config/modules.json').respond(responseData);
        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect($scope.moduleConfig).not.toBe(undefined);
        expect($scope.menuItems.length > 0).toBe(true);
    }));
});});
```

I was expecting to have to run a $scope.$digest() in order to fire the watcher, to get init() to run, but it runs fine as is and the tests pass.

This isn't a problem, I'm just trying to understand why it's running because I don't understand how the watcher is firing? what's causing it to run?

Comment: Where does the `jsDictionary` in `$rootScope.dictionary = jsDictionary;` come from?

Comment: usually, it would come from a json file in the bootstrap, but for testing purposes it's a global javascript object loaded with the test files. It's dirty, but it works while I'm learning to resolve other mistakes I/we've made building our app. All this unit testing is in being done after the build. We're learning so much and in future we'll be taking a TDD approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, it is a bad idea to initialize the controller in global scope. This is because, in future, when you want to test some other controllers which are logically independent, you would still be initializing each controller for every `it()` block, for which I see no reason to do so.

As for why your `$watch` gets fired, you are setting `jsDictionary` to a `$rootScope` and initializing it for each `it()` block. In you controller code, for the `$watch` you are just checking if the value exists, which it will as you set it in the previous lines and hence it calls the `init()` block. The correct way of using the $watch would be:

```
$rootScope.$watch('dictionary', function(oldVal, newVal){
});
```

A better way of doing would be to create a `describe()` block for each controller, put your `beforeEach()` stuff inside the `describe()` and also your `it()` block, those that are related to that particular controller. This would also help you to build modular test cases.

Comment: I have seen watches set up like this, and I do so as well. The dictionary watch is set to check if it exists because we have race issues with it's use before it's set, so, we wait for it like this... HOWEVER, this has since been resolved but the code base i need to work from is on another branch of code where this issue still exists, hence i check for it's existence. I didn't think the watchers ran until a `$digest()` was called? is the `$digest()` being called somewhere automatically?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by initializing the controller in the global scope? this controller is wrapped in IIFE, and its not on $rootScope?

Comment: Angular has many built-in functions that trigger the `$digest()` automatically. Asynchronous calls are one of them. In your code, `$httpBackend.flush()` triggers the digest cycle.

Comment: I was talking about the global scope in test cases and not the actual controller code.

Comment: ah, thanks for the clarification. You've answered both of my questions :)
I have now put the createController function globally and made it create by argument, so each controller is initialized now in the test suits within their own describes, so they are not global.

Comment: this answer, along with the accompanying comments. answer my question :) thanks!